# Amazon Kinesis - Get Count of Records in each Shard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Is there a way to find number of records in each shard for a given stream in Amazon Kinesis?
There is enable enhanced monitoring available but i am not able to find a way to show shard id in cloudwatch, if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enable additional metrics on the kinesis config page in console to capture shard level metrics. unfortunately record count ins't one of the metrics measured. You can look at max iterator age to get a sense of how backed up a shard/stream is.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html#kinesis-metrics-shard

Answer (score 0):

you can use enhanced shard level metrics. In those metrics, you can use `IncomingRecords` metric to get counts of records in a specific time period. An example you can get count of records put into the stream in last 24 hours.